# Image search integration

Tags: search, google-search-api, google-image-search

I'm looking for a solution, where users of my site can use an image search engine (e.g. Google), instead of uploading an image, they can search and pick one of the results.

My problem is:

- Google [image search API](http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/devguide.html) is deprecated!
- Google [custom search](http://www.google.com/cse/) requires me to add "sites to search" when creating a custom search API key. However, I do not want to search my own site, I want to search the internet!

**Which Google API is ment to search images on the internet?**
Would it be plausible to include normal image search in an iframe, and somehow capture an image selection (i.e. when clicked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google made it really difficult:

- http://groups.google.com/group/google-ajax-search-api/browse_thread/thread/9885ea5ab20b8f01?pli=1
- http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1210656

TL;DR: You have to use Google custom search, add a random site when creating the API key, afterwards you can tweak the settings to search the entire web instead.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out LTU technology?

Answer (score 0):

I found this url which JSON - seems to be the top results when searching google images:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=car
```